# Detect when child component is rerendered

Tags: aurelia

I have a link element injected into translation string that I later consume via `aurelia-i18n` plugin. I need to listen for a click event on this link. As far as I researched it is not possible to add `click.trigger="function()` to an html element in translation string.

So I ended up just manually assigning a listener to the link DOM element in `attached` method of parent component. However when language updates, link updates as well and my listener is gone. Is there a way to know when component has been updated so I could reassign the listener there?

Or is a better solution to this issues?

Comment: You can use [`click.delegate`](https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/delegate-vs-trigger#delegate-vs-trigger) on its container element and check the `event.target` to see if it is the element you want.